# How to relogin in facebook with publish permission

Tags: android, android-facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am trying to login into Facebook after I logout with the following code

```
currentSession = Session.getActiveSession();
btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if (currentSession != null) {

                if (!currentSession.isClosed()) {
                    currentSession.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
                    btnLogout.setText("Login");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Successfully logout", 1000).show();
                    Session.setActiveSession(null);
                    // clear your preferences if saved
                } else {
                    Log.d("DEBUG", "IS CLOSED");
                    //m i need to implement login code here? if yes how??

                }

            } else {

                currentSession = new Session(PostFaceBook.this);
                Session.setActiveSession(currentSession);
                btnLogout.setText("Login");
                currentSession.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Successfully logout", 1000).show();
                // clear your preferences if saved
            }

        }
    });
```

So I successfully logout from Facebook. Now how to implement login code(with publish permission) and where?

Comment: have you solved this ?

Comment: NO do you have the solution? @HeshanSandeepa

Comment: can you explain what are you trying to publish(image , video etc) ?

Comment: i want to publish both video , image and status @HeshanSandeepa

Comment: Did you try WebDialog ?

Comment: I can't use webdialog...i have to use my own interface @HeshanSandeepa